# Error pulling image configuration

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

При попытке выполнить docker-compose up -d получаю такую ошибку:

```
ERROR: error pulling image configuration: error parsing HTTP 403 response body: invalid character '<' looking for beginning of value: "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\">\n<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV=\"Content-Type\" CONTENT=\"text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\">\n<TITLE>ERROR: The request could not be satisfied</TITLE>\n</HEAD><BODY>\n<H1>403 ERROR</H1>\n<H2>The request could not be satisfied.</H2>\n<HR noshade size=\"1px\">\nThe Amazon CloudFront distribution is configured to block access from your country.\nWe can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.\n<BR clear=\"all\">\nIf you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.\n<BR clear=\"all\">\n<HR noshade size=\"1px\">\n<PRE>\nGenerated by cloudfront (CloudFront)\nRequest ID: yDh-moBa1cSIHtNWAQV-9YnxBrQueS3nq-ls7zuNyxSLOAMAvUUEsg==\n</PRE>\n<ADDRESS>\n</ADDRESS>\n</BODY></HTML>"
```

Перед ней в командной строке была такая надпись:

```
Pulling lcgfileservicefiles-elasticsearch (docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.13.3)...
7.13.3: Pulling from elasticsearch/elasticsearch
```

Видимо проблема с elasticsearch

Comment: В тексте ошибки указана причина: "The Amazon CloudFront distribution is configured to block access from your country." Используйте образ с docker hub.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!